# date/time field value out of range: "0000-00-00 00:00:00" while using \COPY in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, datetime, copy, import-from-excel

I have a bash script which reads from .csv to a table in PostgreSQL 11.16.The .csv file is generated by mysql select statement.

```
PGPASSWORD="${DATABASE_PASSWORD}" psql -h "${DATABASE_HOST}" -U "${DATABASE_USER}" -p "${DATABASE_PORT}" -d "${DATABASE_NAME}" -c "\COPY backup_nb FROM '$MYPATH\nb.csv' WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER"
```

**ERROR**:  **date/time field value out of range: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
CONTEXT:  COPY backup_nb , line 948, column sscomp: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"**

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE backup_nb
(
    id integer ,
    server character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    sscomp timestamp without time zone
)
```

I know using `nullif('0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00')::timestamp` is a solution
but how to implement this in COPY command??

else is there any other solution??

Comment: You can first import the problematic columns as text, then run an `insert into backup_nb select ... , nullif(sscomp,'0000-00-00 00:00:00')::timestamp from backup_nb_raw;`. If there's nothing in your target table, you can `alter table backup_nb alter column sscomp type text;`, run your import, then `update backup_nb set sscomp=nullif(sscomp,'0000-00-00 00:00:00'); alter table backup_nb alter column sscomp type timestamp using sscomp::timestamp;`

Comment: You can't fix this with the COPY command. The best option is to fix this when exporting the invalid dates from MySQL. Alternatively insert the data into a staging table that uses `text` instead of `timestamp`. Then use `insert ... select ...` to copy the data into the correct table and fixing the invalid date when doing so.